# Macvlan-interface and PPP-session

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt, point-to-point-protocol

I need to pick up two PPP-sessions on the same interface with different MAC-addresses (on some device with openWrt).
I decided to check macvlans. I created an interface with another MAC-address.

```
    ip link add link eth0 address 00:cc:cc:cc:11:33 eth0mac2 type macvlan
    ip link set eth0mac2 up
```

Interface works and I have a connection with other machines (if I assign some ip-address). MAC-address in packets is from this pseudointerface.
PPP-session sets correctly too  (not two sessions, only one; it's just a test) and I can send out some packets (ICMP-request, for example), but I can't receive incoming packets.
I see incoming packets on eth0mac2 by tcpdump:

```
00:07:12.168929 00:18:f3:0a:d1:4c > 00:cc:cc:cc:11:33, ethertype PPPoE S (0x8864), length 15: truncated-pppoe 1
00:07:13.176963 00:18:f3:0a:d1:4c > 00:cc:cc:cc:11:33, ethertype PPPoE S (0x8864), length 15: truncated-pppoe 1
```

But I don't see packets on ppp0 (though packets should be).
On eth0 everything works fine.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular driver for hardware NAT created this problem. 
I got a new version of this driver, and the problem has disappeared